# Trying to compare two strings. Fails because string is always prepended with u"foobar"

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, compare

I have two lists

`list1 = ["foo", "bar"]`

`list2 = ["foo", "bar"]`

I have a method `text_match` which compares two strings:

```
def text_match(self, expected, actual):
    if expected == actual:
        return True
    else:
    return False
```

I call the method

```
self.text_match(list1[0], list2[0])
```

I get false.

When i print the two strings from the list

`list1[0]` >> foo

`list2[1]` >> u"foo"

Why are they not the same when printed?
I've tried encoding, decoding, converting to string.
Nothing works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
def text_match(self, expected, actual):
  if expected == actual:
      return True
  else:
      return False
```

This Error Will Never Give A Chance to the script to Work

Return Flase Couldn't Be In the Same Indent with else: